# How to get second value from Checkbox

Tags: html

I'm using checkbox for trying to return two values

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cproduct" value="{$product.id_product}" value2="{$product.id_product_attribute}" class="add_me_to_cart">

var id_prd = $(item).val(); // val of the checkbox!
```

How can I get second value from checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var value2 = $(item).attr('value2');
```